# External Database Enrolment Plugin "Error reading data from the external course table"

Tags: php, mysql, moodle

I have read this article [External_database_enrolment](https://docs.moodle.org/30/en/External_database_enrolment)

Every thing is fine but when i run the sync.php. I have received below message

I have also add my question here. 
https://moodle.org/mod/forum/discuss.php?d=329150

Please anyone tell me how to resolve this error.

**Error reading data from the external course table.**

Thanks in advance

Regards,

Tariq

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't a development question, however it should be 'pretty easy' to fix, as long as you're working on a dev environment.

Go to site administration -> development -> debugging. And enable the max debugging in the first dropdown, and check the show errors box.

After that, you should attempt to test the settings.

It should reveal to you the error.

If you cannot enable debugging as it's in production, you could still enable max debug, but just not check the checkbox.
After that you can check the server error logs after hitting the 'test'.

Comment: Many thanks due to debugging i have resolve the error.